# Check length char[] before converting to wstring()

Tags: c++, string, winapi

I have a api function. I takes a pointer to array char. The calling function is out of my control. Array is dynamic but still need some checking

```
extern "C" int __stdcall calcW2(LPWSTR foo)
```

If somebody make a call with

```
  char foo[5000];
  LPSTR lpfoo2 = foo;
  calcW2(lpfoo2 );
```

I understand that i need to make some checks. I can test for nulltpr. But if I want to len checking. That the char array has some validity. How is that best done? In the safest way for a string to 0 to 2500 chars. Do need check for something more?

```
if(foo != nullptr)
{
    //Size checking
    //size_t newsize = strlen(SerialNumber) + 1 not good?
    std::wstring test(foo); 
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to check the length?

Answer (score 0):

You missed one important point. The function signature says `LPWSTR` not `LPSTR`. This means that the function expects (or should expect) to receive `wchar_t[]` not `char[]`. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230355.aspx.

I mean:

```
extern "C" int __stdcall calcW2(LPWSTR foo)    <--- LP-W-STR

char foo[5000];
LPSTR lpfoo2 = foo;                        <--- LP-STR
calcW2(lpfoo2 );                          <--- LP-STR passed into LP-W-STR ??
```

that should not compile. Argument types are wrong.

If you change the array to wchar_t[] and it starts to fail to compile, then most probably you have some _UNICODE #defines set wrong. In WINAPI and similar, many functions have dual definitions. When "UNICODE" flag is set, they take LPWSTR, but when the flag is cleared, the headers switch them to taking LPSTR. So if you see that it should be LPWSTR and you want it to be LPWSTR and it insists on being LPSTR, then you either messed up the function names, or UNICODE flag (or the header you have is simply incorrect).

char and wchar_t are different. Simplifying, char is "singlebyte" and wchar_t is "twobyte". Both use '\0' as the end-of-string marker, but in wchar_t that's actually '\0\0' since it's two bytes per character. Also, in wchar_t[] plain ASCII data isn't like `a|b|c|d|e|f`, it's `0|a|0|b|0|c|0|d|0|e|0|f` since it's two bytes per character. That's why the `strlen` cannot work on 16bit encoded data properly - it picks the first \0 from the first character as end-of-string. Having a wchar_t data forcibly packed into char[] is plainly wrong or at least highly misleading and error-prone.

That's why you should use `wstrlen` instead, which so happens to take `wchar_t*` instead of `char*`.

This is a overall 'rule'. For any function working on char (strlen, strcat, strcmp, ..) you should be able to find relevant w* function (wstrlen, wstrcat, wstrcmp, ..). There may be some underscores in the names sometimes. Search the docs. Don't mix up char types. That't now just byte-array. There is some semantics out there for them, and usually if some types are named differently, there's a reason for that.

Comment: Thats ju type. Change the signature to extern "C" int __stdcall calcW2(LPSTR foo). This has nothing to do with wide or ansi only what best Std:: functions to make validity checking.

Comment: @JohanBertilsdotter: So LPWSTR is a typo? OK. Just edit your post then and correct that. But I read what you wrote, and reread second time, and I don't understand what do you what. If there are no wide/char problems, then why are you using char[5000] when your string will be up to 2500chars at max? What "validity" are you talking about all the time? There is no way the data in the array could be "invalid". There can be data, more or less, or no data at all. But the data will be valid. There's no such thing as "invalid character". So, please make it clear: what do you mean by "validity"?

Comment: And if that's really just `char[]` not wchar, then why don't you use the classic `strlen` that you already mentioned? If the char-data is `\0`-terminated then good ol' strlen will work just fine. If the data is terminated by something else, or if you don;t want strlen for some reason, then you will probably need to use `find`/`distance` (std::ish-way) or manual looping (yuck!) to find the data terminator in the array.

Comment: aand if you used [5000] instead of [2500] to add some "overflow" safety, then ... you are not safe. Just tiny bit safer. When "that vile function" pushes more data than 5000chars, you are just as fried as you were with buffer of 2500 chars.